# fragment for flowpane in TornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

The TornadoFX docs [describe using the `ListCellFragment`](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part2/Advanced%20Data%20Controls.html) to bind each cell in a list control to each item model in a list. I am wondering how to do something similar in a `flowpane`. I'd like to use that kind of class to render a bunch of controls and an SVG drawing in each cell. (So it would replace the `button` component in the example code below and somehow bind the `shapeItem` model to it).

```
class LibraryView : View("Current Library") {
    val shapeLibraryViewModel : LibraryViewModel by inject()
    override val root = anchorpane{
        flowpane {
            bindChildren(shapeLibraryViewModel.libraryItemsProperty){
               shapeItem -> button(shapeItem.nameProperty)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I don't see a pre-made class like the one for list view, perhaps I would need to create something similar to it...or maybe there's a more lightweight approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ItemFragment is a bit overkill, since the `itemProperty` of the fragment will never change (a new fragment would be created for every item whenever the `libraryItemsProperty` change. However, if your view logic for each item is substantial, this approach will provide a clean way to separate and contain that logic, so it might be worth it. Here is a complete example you can use as a starting point.

```
class ShapeItemFragment : ItemFragment<ShapeItem>() {
    val shapeModel = ShapeItemModel().bindTo(this)

    override val root = stackpane {
        label(shapeModel.name)
    }
}

class ShapeItem(name: String) {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
}

class ShapeItemModel : ItemViewModel<ShapeItem>() {
    val name = bind(ShapeItem::nameProperty)
}

class LibraryViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val libraryItemsProperty = SimpleListProperty<ShapeItem>(
            listOf(
                    ShapeItem("Shape 1"),
                    ShapeItem("Shape 2")
            ).observable()
    )
}

class LibraryView : View("Current Library") {
    val shapeLibraryViewModel: LibraryViewModel by inject()

    override val root = anchorpane {
        flowpane {
            bindChildren(shapeLibraryViewModel.libraryItemsProperty) { shapeItem ->
                val itemFragment = find<ShapeItemFragment>()
                itemFragment.itemProperty.value = shapeItem
                itemFragment.root
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A slightly lighter version would be to pass the parameter into your fragment manually and just extend Fragment:

```
class ShapeItemFragment : Fragment() {
    val item: ShapeItem by param()

    override val root = stackpane {
        label(item.nameProperty)
    }
}
```

You can still bind to changes to properties inside the `ShapeItem`, since the underlying item won't change (as seen from the ItemFragment) anyway.

Your `bindChildren` statement would then look like this:

```
bindChildren(shapeLibraryViewModel.libraryItemsProperty) { shapeItem ->
    find<ShapeItemFragment>(ShapeItemFragment::item to shapeItem).root
}
```